# Why can't I connect securely to some server twice using sockets in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, network-programming

I've a really strange problem when I try to open a secure connection to a webserver using .Net Sockets.

For most webservers the below code will work just fine but for others it will fail on the second attempt. I cannot figure out why maybe someone can point out the problem to me?

To example code:

```
    protected static void Connect(string hostname, int port, bool secure)
    {
        IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostname);
        Socket socket = null;

        foreach (var ip in ips)
        {
            socket = new Socket(ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Connect(ip, port);
            break;
        }

        NetworkStream LowLevelStream = new NetworkStream(socket);
        SslStream LowLevelSecureStream = new SslStream(LowLevelStream, false, AcceptAllCertifications);
        LowLevelSecureStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, new X509CertificateCollection(), SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Ssl2, false);

        socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        socket.Close();
    }
```

Normally running this code (even more than once) will result in one or more successful connections:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Connect("www.browseemall.com", 443, true);
        Connect("www.browseemall.com", 443, true);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

But for some hosts the same code will result in an exception:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Connect("www.stackoverflow.com", 443, true);
        Connect("www.stackoverflow.com", 443, true);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

[image]

Anybody any idea what that might be (I'm sure it's obvious)? Thanks!

Comment: Translation: _""A call to SSPI failed, see Inner exception" --> "The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.""_. Is the host you're trying really www.stackoverflow.com? What is the purpose of this code?

Comment: Sorry for not providing the translation... I'm not really trying to connect to stackoverflow (it's just an example where the exception is thrown). Other examples would be google.com or bmw.de.

The same is true for some of our internal servers but I cannot disclose the urls for these here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of try and error I've found the solution:

Instead of

```
LowLevelSecureStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, new X509CertificateCollection(), SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Ssl2, false);
```

you need to use

```
LowLevelSecureStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname);
```